# What is the amount I need to tell the customer to get the amount I want in hand

Tags: excel, math

I'm hopelessly stuck on this.

I need to calculate the amount I need to get from the customer, so that after deducting transport charges, commission on the final sale value and bank charges on the final sale value, I will have the amount I want to get.

Example:

The amount I want in hand = 100

Commission @ 7% on final sale value

Bank Charges @ 5% on final sale value

Transport Charges = 10
So, Final sale value = ? (How do I get this figure)

The final sale value is the amount I'll tell the customer, so I'll receive $100 after deducting 7% on the final sale value and 5 % on the Final sale value and the transport charges.

The commission and bank charges are calculated on the final sale value. Eg: If the final sale value is 100, commission @ 7% will be 7 and bank charges will be 5.

[I'm trying to do this in Excel and got stuck good.](http://www.2shared.com/file/4DqiX6YR/calculator.html) Can you please help?

Comment: If the amount you want is `x` than `final-sale-value = x * 1.07 + x * 0.05 + 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is

```
=(Nett + Freight) / (1 - Comm% - Bank%)
```

for your $100 example

```
=(100 + 10) / (1 - 0.07 - 0.05)
=125
```

Comment: This did the job. Thanks very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's math :

Net = Gross - (12 * Gross / 100) - 10

Transfer the 10 and refactor !

Net + 10 = Gross * 88 / 100

Multiply both sides by 100 :

100 * (Net + 10) = Gross * 88

Divide both sides by 88 :

(100 * (Net + 10)) / 88 = Gross